# mapbox map en vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

Muy buenas,

tengo este codigo en el componente AppMap, en el que creo el mapa que posteriormente usaré en una o varias vistas, de momento solo en la pagina Home

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Map -->
    <mapbox-map class="h-20 w-32" :accessToken="myAccessToken">
      <mapbox-marker :lngLat="[10, 10]" />
    </mapbox-map>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { MapboxMap } from "vue-mapbox-ts";

export default {
  name: "app-map",
  data() {
    return {
      myAccessToken:
        "pk.eyJ1Ijoib3NjYXJwbHVtYXJpZWdhIiwiYSI6ImNrd291cGRoODA0dW8yb3FobmdnYzNveGEifQ.FSlGubVkceUDi1-bUfZ4Kw",
    };
  },
  components: {
    MapboxMap,
  },
};
</script>
```

y aqui la vista Home

```
<template>
  <div>
    <app-map />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { AppMap } from "@/components/AppMap.vue";

export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    AppMap
  }
};

</script>
```

el caso es que no me aparece el mapa y ni siquiera la llamada a la api, no encuentro el problema...

Gracias y un saludo